# Node.JS with mysql promise

Tags: node.js

I want to retrieve some data from a mysql server with a node.js server.
I also want to use the async mechanism.

My code is:

```
app.get('/test/:id', async (req, res) => {

      const connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConnData);
      const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `courses`');

      return res.send({});
});
```

The result is:

```
TypeError: connection.execute is not a function
    at ...........server.js:48:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:21400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `connection.connect();` Also I'm not sure `execute()` is the right function to use. I think it should be `query()`

```js
app.get('/test/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConnData);

    await connection.connect();

    const rows = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM `courses`');

    return res.send({});
});
```

Also, don't forget to close the connection with `connection.end();`